# xRDP autostart Applications, Clipit problem

Tags: debian, clipboard, autostart, xrdp

**The Problem:** The company I work for has branched to another location a couple of days ago and our inhouse software has trouble keeping up with the data it sends and receives (in other words: Users from the new location correctly claim that the software is running too slow).
Since there's no way to shrink the data, I intent to force the users onto a debian terminal server with xrdp that automatically runs the software without the user having to do anything (essentially like Citrix).

In essence: Everyone gets their personalized rdp file onto their desktop, they start it, the rdp connection starts automatically and runs the application.

edit: I use LXDE Desktop

So far, I manage to autostart the application and it works fine, but the problem is that I currently run the application way before the desktop environment loads, which means that clipit doesn't start and people can't use the clipboard at all. I tried weaving the clipit process into the loader (exec clipit -d before running wine in the /opt/xrdp/loader file) but since it waits for "clipit to finish" (which technically never happens) the process gets stuck there. Maybe someone has an idea to get clipit to start together with the application? I wouldnt mind if people see the virutal desktop for a moment, but I have no idea how to "autorun" applications after the desktop loaded. I suspected **/etc/xrdp/reconnectwm.sh** was able to do that but when I try to run my loader-script from there, it does absolutely nothing.

**My current attempt** (replacing unchanged/unimportant stuff with [...])**:**

**/etc/xrdp/startwm.sh**

```
#!/bin/sh
# xrdp X session start script (c) 2015, 2017 mirabilos
# published under The MirOS Licence

if test -r /etc/profile; then
    . /etc/profile
fi


[...] 

if test -r /etc/profile; then
    . /etc/profile
fi

# START SCRIPT TO COPY FILES AND START APPLICATION
/opt/xrdp/loader

test -x /etc/X11/Xsession && exec /etc/X11/Xsession

exec /bin/sh /etc/X11/Xsession
```

As you can see, I call /opt/xrdp/loader before calling the Xsession. So it doesn't really load the desktop or anything, which is fine because I don't really need the desktop environment).

**/opt/xrdp/loader**

```
#!/bin/bash

# COPY WINE FILES
# I generated the full wine configuration and use it as a template
cp -r /opt/wine/. ~/.wine

# run wine and load the inhouse software.
wine explorer /desktop=$USER-$RANDOM,1920x1080 "C:\Inhouse\Software.exe"

# kill processes including xrdp upon closing the software.
pkill -u $USER
```

With that setup, people can connect to the machine via RDP and it opens up the software perfectly fine, but the clipboard doesn't work. Neither host to rdp direction or vice versa. Is there a way to get the clipboard to work?